# Amount in words should come automatically after total amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I have fields like tax_1_amount, tax_2_amount, tax_3_amount, invoice_amount and total_invoice_amount. When the total invoice amount is calculated then the amount_in_words field should be automatically updated by the total amount in words. Total amount is calculated as follows:

```
@total_tax_amount = @invoice.tax_1_amount + @invoice.tax_2_amount + @invoice.tax_3_amount
@total_amount = @total_tax_amount + @invoice.invoice_amount
```

Can anyone tell me if there is any generator or any gem for that. Or what code shall I write for that.

Comment: you should accept answers that solve your problem or at least helped to.

Comment: I am not getting how I have to accept

Answer (score 1):

You need to

```
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
```

if trying to use anywhere other than a view.

Comment: This was it! Hope it still helps. Using rails 6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood but check this links

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human

or

https://github.com/bcarrere/currency-in-words

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think the second link is useful for me.

Comment: I installed currency-in-words gem and then did bundle install but when I tried this gem on the console, it is showing this error: undefined method `number_to_currency_in_words' for main:Object.